# pandoc cannot change width text

Tags: width, pandoc, converters

I am using pandoc on Ubuntu to convert a markdown file to pdf:

```
pandoc -o output.pdf ProjectDescription.md
```

However I find the text to be too narrow, and I want to use more of the page. For this, I read pandoc manual and it looks like the columns option should be good:

https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html

''
--columns=NUMBER

Specify length of lines in characters. This affects text wrapping in the generated source code (see --wrap). It also affects calculation of column widths for plain text tables (see Tables below).
''

Default is supposed to be columns=72.

But trying:

```
pandoc --columns=80 -o output.pdf ProjectDescription.md
```

does not give me a wider text. Do you know why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This affects text wrapping in the generated source code

Thus this has no effect on PDF output for which there is only the intermediary LaTeX source.

You probably want to [set the margins](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex) like:

```
---
title: my doc
margin-left: 1cm
---

# my content
```